# Calculate the product price for each product Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am having the data as the picture.

Question: How can I extract the product and price as columns and calculate the price for each product?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cOpCH.png)

I already using regex to extract the product and quantity but stuck in the next step.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gGK6n.png)

Comment: Please see [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples). Screenshots of data and code are not useful.

Comment: are you only given sums and you want to find out individual prices from that? If that's the case - you would need to solve it as a set of linear equations - something like sympy - https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/solvers.html

Comment: @avloss, thank you so much. Thanks guys, I tried with sympy and received a great outcome